# Hide DIV if all option disabled

Tags: html, css

Simple question but and I need simple solution.
I need to hide div if all option are disabled.

```css
.HIDE select option:disabled {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="HIDE">
  <select>
    <option disabled>1</option>
    <option disabled>2</option>
    <option disabled>3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I need to hide  than all  are disabled. 
Here is fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/beauto/fey1x52o/6/

Comment: CSS can't help you here. You would need to use JavaScript or hide the div before generating the HTML. Presumably you have some logic that disables the options that could be leveraged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery

```js
function check(){
  var disabled=false;
  $.each($("option"), function( i, l ){
   if($(l).attr("disabled")!="disabled"){
      disabled=true
   }
  });
  console.log(disabled);
  if(!disabled){$("select").css({"display":"none"})}
}
check();
```

```css
.HIDE > select option:disabled {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="HIDE">
<select>
<option disabled>1</option>
<option disabled>2</option>
<option disabled>3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: OP is looking for a CSS only solution, thats why. and That's why the question is closed

Comment: @pc_coder possible somehow hide <div> if one value selected others disabled?
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/beauto/fey1x52o/13/

Comment: Yes possible http://jsfiddle.net/gywc3h5j/ just checking if count of not disabled elements equals one .